# edges sharp though edge split modifier not added

Tags: mesh, modifiers, edges

Hello Blender Community,

I imported an OBJ mesh into Blender. When I set the shading to smooth some edges appear sharp and others don't, though I haven't added the edge split modifier.

If I go into Edit Mode I can see the blue lines indicating the sharp lines. I already checked if there are doubles by merging vertexes by distance and I checked if the normals are all pointing in the right direction.
Does anybody know what happened here?

Here's a picture of the object:
[image]
Here's a pictuer of the object in edit mode:
[image]

Comment: Clear split normals. In the object data section> Normals> clear custom split normals data

Comment: You say that you imported the mesh. Then it's likely that those edges/smoothing groups comes from the imported mesh.
Hard edges are not the same as split edges. The faces can share common vertices even if the edge is sharp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out by myself now: In Properties > Object Data > Normals > Auto Smooth.
It's kinda like Edge split but not as an Modifier but it works the same, maybe even better.